# Prevent animation on UIPopover dismissed by tap outside?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

When a user taps outside the popover, the dismissal is animated. Is there a way to set that dismissal animation to NO? I have googled and searched on Stack extensively.

The docs for UIPopover state:

> When displayed, taps outside of the popover window cause the popover
>   to be dismissed automatically. To allow the user to interact with the
>   specified views and not dismiss the popover, you can assign one or
>   more views to the passthroughViews property. Taps inside the popover
>   window do not automatically cause the popover to be dismissed. Your
>   view and view controller code must handle actions and events inside
>   the popover explicitly and call the dismissPopoverAnimated: method as
>   needed.

I have implemented the `dismissPopoverAnimated:` method with `NO` and that works great for all the cases when I call that method.

The problem is when a user taps outside the popover to dismiss, `dismissPopoverAnimated:` is not called.

> taps outside of the popover window cause the popover
>   to be dismissed automatically.

*And that dismissal is animated.* There seems to be no way to control that dismissal. I am using the popover to present a color picker for a drawing app. Taps to draw are not registered until the popover has finished animating out. This creates a noticeable delay as you are not able to draw immediately but must wait for the animation to complete.

I thought that `- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` could work but there is no way AFAIK to set the animation property in this method. Just return yes or no.

Is there a different method I can implement to be able to set the animation to NO?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the view controller that presents your UIPopoverController, conform to the UIPopoverControllerDelegate protocol and implement the following delegate method. I just tested this and it does dismiss the popover without animation.

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

Just make sure that you have set the delegate of your popover controller to the view controller that implements this.

Comment: Thanks so much! Don't know how I couldn't get this to work. Spent forever on it. Hat tip to you.

Comment: This method is depreciated in iOS 9.0+ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopovercontrollerdelegate/1624661-popovercontrollershoulddismisspo

Comment: `UIPopoverController` has been deprecated as of iOS 8 and be replaced with `UIPopoverPresentationController`. So the new protocol which has an identical method named `popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover` can be found in the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

This will disable the animation, when we close the popOver by tapping outside.

```
extension YourViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

  func presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) -> Bool {
        // to prevent animation, we need to dismiss it manuallly with animated: false
        presentationController.presentingViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        return true
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 9+ as by default `modalPresentationStyle = .Popover` you can implement this method to prevent dismiss clicking out

```
public func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```